# Sheafification, stalks and quotient

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I gave a problem that I can't finish by myself. Any help would be appreciated.

Consider a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of abelian groups on a topological space.

I would like to show that given two sheaves $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F}'$ we get $\mathcal{F}_x/\mathcal{F}'_x \cong (\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{F}')_x$. This question has been addressed here: [Stalk of the quotient presheaf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/678571/stalk-of-the-quotient-presheaf), but with no accepted answer, and the answers that are there didn't help me much. I was hoping that this could be proven without going into category theory explicitly (as was suggested in one answer to that question). I already figured that one should take the sheaf generated by $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{F}'$, call it $\mathcal{G}$, and then one can consider the following exact sequence: $\mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}' \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$, where the second map is the composition of the quotient map with the natural morphism $\tau: \mathcal{F}/\mathcal{F}' \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$. Where to go from here, or if I am right so far, I do not know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approach this directly. It seems to me that you are using $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{F}'$ to refer to the pre-sheaf quotient, I feel I should mention that it is more standard to give the pre-sheaf some other notation (such as $\mathcal{Q}$) and then use $\mathcal{F}/\mathcal{F}'$ for the sheafification of the pre-sheaf quotient, to emphasise that this sheaf is a cokernel for $\psi:\mathcal{F}'\rightarrow \mathcal{F}$. This is the notation that I will use.

An element of the stalk $\mathcal{Q}_x$ is a pair $(s,U)$ such that $s \in \mathcal{Q}(U)$, i.e. $s = \bar{f}$ where $f \in \mathcal{F}(U)$ and $\bar{f}$ is the image of $f$ in the quotient $\mathcal{F}(U)/(\psi(U)(\mathcal{F}'(U))$.

Then we may define a group homomorphism $\pi_x:\mathcal{F}_x\rightarrow \mathcal{Q}_x$ by $(f,U)\mapsto (\bar{f},U)$. Then you need to show that this is surjective and that the kernel is $\psi_x(\mathcal{F}'_x)$.

If we take the natural projection homomorphism $\pi:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{Q}$, $\pi_x$ is just the map of stalks induced by $\pi$, so it really is a very natural map to use. In fact, this approach is exactly how you show that the sequence of sheaves $\mathcal{F}'\rightarrow\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}/\mathcal{F}'\rightarrow 0$ is exact, since $\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}/\mathcal{F}'$ is the composition of $\pi$ and the canonical map $\varphi:\mathcal{Q}\rightarrow \mathcal{F}/\mathcal{F}'$, and we know that $\varphi_x$ is an isomorphism on stalks for all $x$.

Comment: That helped. Thanks. I am not quite sure what there is to prove with the surjectivity (other than what you said in the construction) and the kernel of $\pi_x$. Is there something that is not obvious there?

Comment: @user198182 You're welcome. I would say that both things are very straightforward to prove and could reasonably be said to be obvious. I try and avoid saying it where possible since something being obvious is always relative. But I'm glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

We have an exact sequence

$$0 \to \mathcal F' \to \mathcal F \to \mathcal F/\mathcal F' \to 0$$

This means that this sequence is exact at stalks, hence for all $x$ we have an exact seuqnece

$$0 \to \mathcal F'_x \to \mathcal F_x \to (\mathcal F/\mathcal F')_x \to 0$$

which immediately shows $(\mathcal F/\mathcal F')_x \cong \mathcal F'_x / \mathcal F_x$.

Comment: Why do we have the first exact sequence? The exact sequences of presheaves are defined in terms of the exactness on all the stalks (i.e. what you have in the second exact sequence), so I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: By the definition of the quotient, we get the exaxt sequence first on the presheaf-level. But then sheafification is exact, hence we have the desired exaxt sequence. If you do not understand this well, you should really have at least three or four more looks at this before you go on. Everything else in alg. geometry will else kill you.